# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths- crahes application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        NSLog(@"delet it");
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
```

Why is this crashing my application?

Comment: How are `numberOfSections` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` coded up?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to delete the item from your datasource.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete your cell row's data before you call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

UITableView will check your data source object for number of row in section. If your new returned value of number of rows does not equal to old number of rows minus one, you'll be in trouble.